# How to fix EdgeWeights when a vertex is deleted from a directed graph (BUG?)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-review, code-request

I have the following Codes (developed by @Mr.Wizard and @kglr, respectively):

```
multiplierB[M_?MatrixQ, 
sec_Integer] := ((#/Tr[#] & /@ N[M\[Transpose]])\[Transpose] // 
 Take[#, sec, sec] & // Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sec] - #] &);

UnweightedTransmission[matrixA_?MatrixQ,matrixB_?MatrixQ,t1_Real, 
 t2_Real] :=
 Module[{indices = 
    Union @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
     FindPath[
      AdjacencyGraph[
       Map[Boole[t1 <= # <= t2] &, 
        matrixA, {-1}]], #[[1]], #2[[1]], \[Infinity], All])}, 
HighlightGraph[
 Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ indices, 
  EdgeWeight -> Extract[matrixB, indices], 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ##3], {#, #2}]] &;
```

Example: Using the above Codes, I perform the following calculations:

```
mat = {{10, 60, 5, 9, 12, 4}, {20, 30, 40, 30, 30, 50}, {10, 20,  20, 90, 60, 200}, {30, 12, 24, 120, 90, 324}, {6, 24, 12, 21, 15,  222}, {24, 54, 299, 330, 93, 0}};  
multp = multiplierB[mat, 5];
SeedRandom[01];
trans = RandomInteger[6, {5, 5}];

gr1 = UnweightedTransmission[multp, trans, 0.1, 1.5][{1}, {5}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"]
gr1 = Graph[gr1, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
   GraphEmbedding[gr1]];  (*fixes the vertex coordinates of "gr"*)
```

Below, I show the original digraph `gr1` (on the left) and the digraph after deleting vertex `2` from `gr1` (on the right). Obviously, `EdgeWeight`s in `gr1` are not preserved in the digraph on the right. How can I fix the coordinates of edges and weights in `gr1` after deleting vertex `2` from `gr1`? I tried the above operations with various examples, and all of them give the contradictory mapping of the edge weights after deleting a vertex from the original digraph.

```
{gr1, VertexDelete[gr1, {2}]}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen on 12.1.1 for me - edge 1-5 stays zero, edge 5-4 stays 4. Perhaps you could work around it by deleting the incident edges first, then deleting the vertex `VertexDelete[EdgeDelete[gr1, IncidenceList[gr1, 2]], 2]` which might prevent it from redistributing the weights.

Comment: @flinty: Yes...Your suggestion worked well. Now I do not have any trouble mixing edge weights. Thank you very much.